# Copying/Manipulating Formatted Text in Textboxes in Excel 2013 using VBA

Tags: excel, textbox, excel-2013, vba

I am trying to do two things in Excel 2013 using VBA:

1. Get FORMATTED text from a Textbox, and manipulate it (like HTML perhaps). And
2. Copy FORMATTED text from a Textbox, to another Textbox.

I have tried two things:

```
'Copies text only. No formatting, but with proper line breaks
Dim txtContent As String
txtContent = Worksheets("TextBox").Shapes("TextBox1").TextFrame.Characters.Text
Worksheets("TextBox").Shapes("TextBox 3").TextFrame.Characters.Text = txtContent
```

The second approach was similar to above:

```
'Does not do anything. Produces Run-time error 91
Dim myFrame As TextFrame
myFrame = Worksheets("TextBox").Shapes("TextBox1").TextFrame
Worksheets("TextBox").Shapes("TextBox 3").TextFrame = myFrame
```

Please help.

Comment: Results are in the comments in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either **set** or **retrieve** the formatting of text characters in a TextBox as follows:

```
Sub durall()
    ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Font.ColorIndex = 3
End Sub
```

Comment: This actually led me to find out that there's a bunch of options (or things to copy) from the Font object. Thanks. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840959.aspx

Answer (score 6):

```
Sub Tester()
    CopyText ActiveSheet.Shapes("txtOne").TextFrame, _
             ActiveSheet.Shapes("txtTwo").TextFrame
End Sub



Sub CopyText(tf1 As TextFrame, tf2 As TextFrame)

    Dim n, f As Font

    tf2.Characters.Text = tf1.Characters.Text

    For n = 1 To tf1.Characters.Count
        Set f = tf1.Characters(n, 1).Font
        With tf2.Characters(n, 1).Font
            .Bold = f.Bold
            .Color = f.Color
            .Italic = f.Italic
            'add other properties as needed...
        End With
    Next n
End Sub
```

Comment: Yours is the better answer **(+1)**

Comment: I'd vote this up but I'm a new user. I'd still reward you Gary for a speedy response. :)